# Background images only load sometimes

Tags: html, css

http://eji.justgotnoobcoiled.com:8081/index.htm

Hit refresh a few times. It happens more often in chrome.

Any thoughts...?

Comment: What have you tried so far to rectify this problem? What's the file-size of the background image? If you don't put any effort in to constructing your question, why do you think people will put any effort into helping you?

Comment: **503** ;-)! It doesn't even come to background image :p.

Answer (score 1):

It's working fine for me. As such, I suspect it's a hosting issue. (Whether or not you get *any* content is pretty much hit and miss.)

That said, as you're using a PNG some older browsers (IE 6, etc.) won't support this without a workaround. As such, using a JPEG (or even a GIF) would probably be wiser.

Answer (score 0):

Server issue. It's no longer loading for me at all.

@middaparka

IE 6 does support PNG what it doesn't support very well is the alpha transparency of PNG - which JPEG and GIF don't provide on any browser.

PNGs are the best image format to use. They can compess better than GIFs, they are better quality than JPEGs and with a little help the alpha transparency can be made to work on IE 6, as well as natively on IE 7+ and proper browsers.